# JAXB xjc: Resolving Illegal Class Inheritance Loop When Generating Classes from AUTOSAR XSD

Tags: xml, xsd, autosar

I'm working with JAXB's xjc tool to generate Java classes from an AUTOSAR XSD file and encountered an IllegalArgumentException indicating an illegal class inheritance loop. Here's the error message I received:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal class inheritance loop.  Outer class TargetIPduRefElement may not subclass from inner class: TargetIPduRefElement
        at com.sun.tools.xjc@4.0.3/com.sun.codemodel.JDefinedClass._extends(JDefinedClass.java:247)
        at com.sun.tools.xjc@4.0.3/com.sun.tools.xjc.generator.bean.ImplStructureStrategy$1._extends(ImplStructureStrategy.java:96)
        at com.sun.tools.xjc@4.0.3/com.sun.tools.xjc.generator.bean.BeanGenerator.<init>(BeanGenerator.java:187)
        at com.sun.tools.xjc@4.0.3/com.sun.tools.xjc.generator.bean.BeanGenerator.generate(BeanGenerator.java:141)
        at com.sun.tools.xjc@4.0.3/com.sun.tools.xjc.model.Model.generateCode(Model.java:259)
        at com.sun.tools.xjc@4.0.3/com.sun.tools.xjc.Driver.run(Driver.java:365)
        at com.sun.tools.xjc@4.0.3/com.sun.tools.xjc.Driver.run(Driver.java:198)
        at com.sun.tools.xjc@4.0.3/com.sun.tools.xjc.Driver._main(Driver.java:117)
        at com.sun.tools.xjc@4.0.3/com.sun.tools.xjc.Driver$1.run(Driver.java:76)
```

Has anyone encountered a similar issue and found a way to resolve it? I'd appreciate any insights or suggestions on how to debug this problem.

Comment: Could you share the xsd location ?

Comment: @Laurent Schoelens  Thank you very much for your reply. Here is the download link for the AUTOSAR documentation[link](https://www.autosar.org/search?tx_solr%5Bq%5D=xsd) (AUTOSAR_MMOD_XMLSchema.zip). I am looking to parse the 'autosar.xsd' file within it into Java classes using the xjc command. If you have any further suggestions or information, I would be immensely grateful.

Comment: Could you please share the direct link to the zip file ? There is 228 Documents in the link you shared. Thanks

Comment: @Laurent Schoelens oh,sorry. Here is the direct link to the zip file.[link](https://www.autosar.org/fileadmin/standards/R18-10_R4.4.0_R1.5.0/CP/AUTOSAR_MMOD_XMLSchema.zip) . Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to make xjc compile your XSD (from your link), I had to add the following binding file

```xml
<jaxb:bindings version="3.0"
               xmlns:jaxb="https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jaxb"
               xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

  <jaxb:bindings schemaLocation="AUTOSAR_00046.xsd" node="/xs:schema">
    <!--
      Fixes :
      Simple type "{0}" was not mapped to Enum due to EnumMemberSizeCap limit. Facets count: {1}, current limit: {2}. You can use customization attribute "typesafeEnumMaxMembers" to extend the limit.
    -->
    <jaxb:globalBindings typesafeEnumMaxMembers="1024" />

    <!--
      Fixes Property "{0}" is already defined. Use &lt;jaxb:property> to resolve this conflict.
    -->
    <jaxb:bindings node="//xs:attributeGroup[@name='ENTRY']//xs:attribute[@name='BGCOLOR']">
      <jaxb:property name="BGCOLORAttr"></jaxb:property>
    </jaxb:bindings>

    <!--
      Fixes Complex type and its child element share the same name "{0}". Use a class customization to resolve this conflict.
    -->
    <jaxb:bindings node="//xs:group[@name='COMPU-SCALES']/xs:sequence/xs:element[@name='COMPU-SCALES']/xs:complexType">
      <jaxb:class name="CompuScalesElement"/>
    </jaxb:bindings>
    <jaxb:bindings node="//xs:group[@name='TARGET-I-PDU-REF']/xs:sequence/xs:element[@name='TARGET-I-PDU-REF']/xs:complexType">
      <jaxb:class name="TargetIPduRefElement"/>
    </jaxb:bindings>
  </jaxb:bindings>
</jaxb:bindings>
```

This will resolve the problem encounter without any binding file :

- `typesafeEnumMaxMembers="1024"` will solve the enum not being generated (adjust according max members)
- "Property XXX is already defined. Use <jaxb:property> to resolve this conflict." for `BGCOLOR` attribute
- "Complex type and its child element share the same name XXX" for both `TARGETIPDUREF` and `COMPUSCALES`

If not using jaxb3/4 (jakarta-based), you can change the header of the file to make it compatible to jaxb2 with the following

```xml
<jaxb:bindings version="2.1"
               xmlns:jaxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb"
               xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
```

Comment: Thank you very much,bro. you have helped me solve a problem that has troubled me for a long time.

Comment: Hey buddy, if you have time, could you take a look at this issue? I would be very grateful.[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77918670/resolving-error-with-xpath-evaluation-yielding-too-many-target-nodes)