# Resolving Error with XPath Evaluation Yielding Too Many Target Nodes

Tags: xml, xsd

I am attempting to change the all-uppercase class names generated by xjc to CamelCase. To achieve this, I have written a Python script to generate a binding file. Here is a part of the script:

```
def generate_bindings_for_node(node_type, xpath):
    for node in root.findall(xpath, namespaces):
        name = node.get('name')
        if name:
           
            unique_xpath = f"{xpath}[@name='{name}']"
            bindings = ET.SubElement(bindings_root, 'jaxb:bindings', {
                'node': unique_xpath
            })
            ET.SubElement(bindings, node_type, {
                'name': to_camel_case(name)
            })
```

However, when running my Python script to create the binding file, I encountered the many following errors like this:

[ERROR] ".//xsd:element[@name='CONTEXT-COMPONENT-REF']" XPath evaluation resulted in too many (16) target nodes

This is the link to the XSD file[link][This is the link to the XSD file](https://www.autosar.org/fileadmin/standards/R18-10_R4.4.0_R1.5.0/CP/AUTOSAR_MMOD_XMLSchema.zip).

Can anyone help solve the issue of generating class names in CamelCase?

Comment: Best option would be to use the [XJC CamelCase plugin](https://github.com/highsource/jaxb-tools/wiki/JAXB-CamelCase-Plugin) but we didn't publish the 4.0.1 version of jaxb-tools yet that include this change.

Comment: @Laurent Schoelens
 oh，are there any other recommended methods

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to get rid of the following message in the binding file :

> [ERROR] ".//xsd:element[@name='CONTEXT-COMPONENT-REF']" XPath evaluation resulted in too many (16) target nodes

You can use the `multiple` attribute with one of the following value `true` / `yes` / `1`

That will tell XJC that if the node targets more than one XPath, it's normal and he can proceed.

For reference : you can also use the `required` attribute with one of the following value `false` / `no` / `0` that will tell XJC that if XPath doesn't match any node, it's not important and he can continue to proceed.

When the [XJC CamelCase Plugin](https://github.com/highsource/jaxb-tools/wiki/JAXB-CamelCase-Plugin) will be available in it's jakarta form (in jaxb-tools 4.0.1), the best option would be to use this plugin and remove the binding file.